# How to dynamically make text fit squarely into an area

Tags: php, html, css, layout, text

I am designing a website with a similar layout qualities to http://Obvious.com (will transfer to Medium). I have noticed a few great things about their layout and there is one aspect that I do not know how to do.

On the home page, when it comes to the lines of text underneath the headline of each blogpost I see that there is always a fixed area and the text fits neatly square within the text area. ALSO if the headline is longer the text below adjusts accordingly.

How is this done? I have tried a method that counts the number of characters in a string and when headline is longer, the chosen character amount is less by x characters...BUT when doing this, sometimes there is just one word or two that hangs into the next line therefore giving an uneven look. (I don't want uneven looks)

So is there a way to make sure that the text will always fit to the end of the line? And the amount of text will change depending upon the size of the headline WHILE fitting?

Is this a PHP solution? Perhaps CSS? Javascript? (ps those are languages I know I can work with)

Please visit Obvious.com(trans to Medium) for reference.

Comment: Can you specify which specific elements you are referring to?

Examples of code would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a css div with a certain width

```
<div style="width:300px; height:400px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tempor justo quis urna hendrerit placerat. Ut fringilla rutrum nulla at rutrum. Nullam sagittis accumsan erat et venenatis. Maecenas luctus magna rutrum neque aliquet dictum at quis libero. Mauris at felis dolor. Nam sit amet euismod purus. Etiam tincidunt laoreet dui ut fermentum.</div>
```

Here's a JsFiddle I made http://jsfiddle.net/RZFYH/

Comment: Won't work, you're forgetting the overflow. Add more text and see what happens. You have to set overflow:hidden as I said above or the content will overrun the div.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source, you'll see that more text than is actually displayed is passed to the browser. What they're doing is returning the first x characters of an article (in the output HTML generated by, say, PHP) and then clipping the container element with CSS. The x value needs to be predetermined with trial-and-error, but nothing fancy is really going on.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/clip and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-overflow for details on CSS text clipping

Comment: They're just making the element a fixed size and setting overflow:hidden. Has nothing to do with x number of characters other than the snippet created by whatever CMS they're using. That however isn't what's controlling how many characters fit the box.  http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/RZFYH/1/

Comment: Yes, sorry: It's not really clipping, it's overflow as you say (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow). Regarding the x characters: Sure you *could* return all the characters in a document, but the purpose of returning the first x is to avoid returning too much data as, after a certain number, it won't be visible and that's a waste of bandwidth. It's not directly related, but it's relevant.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I looked through your answers and things are clearer. I have thought of making a fixed area and then using the overflow property, but something was just not right about it. Also, I did not know about the text-overflow property (I'm surprised I did not). I'm going to apply the above mentioned methods as I think I will get the desired result.